# Set User Role in loopback using loopback-component-passport into inbuilt models

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to create user in loopback using npm `loopback-component-passport` with user roles based on a condition,

1. If user is having property `isAdmin:true` he should have role of `admin`
2. If user is having property `isAdmin:false` he should have role of `user`

Here is my code:

```
if (form.$valid) {
        AuthService.register({
          name: $scope.user.name,
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password,
          isAdmin: $scope.user.isAdmin
        })
          .then(function() {
            // Account created, redirect to home
            $state.go('home');
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            err = err.data;
            $scope.errors = {};

            // Update validity of form fields that match the mongoose errors
            angular.forEach(err.errors, function(error, field) {
              form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);
              $scope.errors[field] = error.message;
            });
        });
}
```

**Factory:**

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('AuthService', ['User', '$q', '$rootScope', function(User, $q, $rootScope) {
    function login(email, password) {
      return User
        .login({email: email, password: password})
        .$promise
        .then(function(response) {
          $rootScope.currentUser = {
            id: response.user.id,
            tokenId: response.id,
            email: email
          };
        });
    }

    function logout() {
      return User
        .logout()
        .$promise
        .then(function() {
          $rootScope.currentUser = null;
        });
    }

    function register(user) {
      return User.create(user).$promise;
    }

    return {
      login: login,
      logout: logout,
      register: register
    };
  }]);
```

**Passport strategy:**

```
 "local": {
    "provider": "local",
    "module": "passport-local",
    "usernameField": "email",
    "passwordField": "password",
    "authPath": "/auth/local",
    "successRedirect": "/auth/account",
    "failureRedirect": "/local",
    "failureFlash": true
      },
   ... 
   ...
```

**model-config.json**

```
{ 
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  }
}
```

But now I have no clue how to add role so that I can differentiate users with user roles. How can I set user roles in `loopback-component-passport`'s inbuilt model?

Comment: *"How can I set user roles?"*  Question is far too vague ...set them where? Not clear at all what your problem is

Comment: @charlietfl Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially create a file and add roles in DB
**server/boot/role.js**:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var Role = app.models.Role;
  Role.create([
      {name: 'admin'},
      {name: 'user'}]
    , function(err, role) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Created roles:', role);
    });
};
```

Use Model hooks methods
**https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks**

**server/boot/user.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var User = app.models.user;
  var Role = app.models.Role;
  var RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;
  User.observe('after save', function setDefaultUsername(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.instance) {
      if (ctx.isNewInstance) {
        var userRole = ctx.instance.isAdmin ? 'admin' : 'user';
        Role.findOne({where: {name: userRole}}, function(err, role) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
          RoleMapping.create({
            principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
            principalId: ctx.instance.id,
            roleId: role.id
          }, function(err, roleMapping) {
            if (err) {
              return console.log(err);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
    next();
  });
};
```

View full example on [**Github**](https://github.com/vicky-gonsalves/loopback-demo)